# Calculating $ \int_1^n \int_1^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{x^4 + y^2} dx \, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am currently trying to calculate this integral but it is giving me quite a bit of trouble. Would you guys mind giving me suggestions?

$$ \int_1^n \int_1^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{x^4 + y^2} dx \, dy$$
where $n$ is a natural number.

EDIT: The answer to this problem is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.This problem is #2285 from Demidovich's Mathematical Analysis book.

Comment: Well, the first step suggests itself to be partial fractions, but how far along have you gotten?

Comment: I actually haven't tried using partial fractions. Sorry, I'm currently editing this post.

First, I decided to make the substitution $x = \sqrt{ y*tan(t) }$. It appears I have found a possible solution though; I will post an update in a few minutes.

Comment: Nevermind, doing said substitution we obtain the following integral.

$$ \int \frac{1}{2*y^\frac{3}{2}} \int cot(t)^\frac{1}{2} dt dy$$
which eventually leads me to an even worse looking integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We don't really want to integrate first with respect to $x$, with respect to $y$ is much better.

For integrating first with respect to $y$, note that the denominator is $x^4\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^4}\right)$, and make the substitution $y=x^2 u$.

More: Note that $y$  goes from $x^2$ to $n$.

Comment: Right, as a result $$ dy = x^2du $$ then after substituting we obtain the following integral: $$ \int_1^n \frac{1}{x^2}arctan(\frac{n^2}{x^2}) - \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{x^2} dx $$

Comment: From here, I chose to use the substitution $w = \frac{n}{x}$, by which we have that $dw = -n \frac{1}{x^2}dx$, substituting once again we obtain the integral: $$ \int_n^1 \frac{-1}{n} arctan(w^2) dw$$ I tried solving the last integral using Matlab's Mupad but I wind up getting a complex result. Did I mess up at some point or should I try a different substitution?

Comment: Remember the limits of integration on $y$, which goes from $x^2$ to $n$.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Then the integral we must evaluate is $$\int_1^\sqrt{n} \int_{x^2}^n \frac{1}{x^4+y^2} dy \ dx$$ and substituting what we had, we obtain the following integral $$\int_1^\sqrt{n} \frac{1}{x^2} arctan(\frac{n}{x^2}) - \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$$ Once again, substituting $w = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{x}$ then $dw = \frac{-\sqrt{n}}{x^2}$: $$\int_\sqrt{n}^1 \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}} arctan(w^2) dw - \frac{\pi}{4} (\frac{1}{n} - 1)$$ Any suggestions on how to evaluate the remaining integral?

EDIT: I apologize for reposting, I am still learning how to use Mathjax.